# make js files not viewable in browser debug window

Tags: javascript, security, browser

Is there a way to make my js files not viewable or debuggable through browsers developper tools?

Greetz Andy

Comment: why you want to do that? is it some kind o security issue? because if so, then you should consider handling all sensible datas server side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The browser needs to be able to read and execute your scripts, which means that in any case it has got *something* to show to the user in the debugging tools. You might try to obfuscate your script, but Chrome has a "pretty print" mode which reformats the Javascript back to a readable spacing and indentation (obfuscated function and variable names might still make it a bit harder to read).

Comment: where's the pretty print option?  I've never seen it.

Comment: Open devtools, go to "Scripts" pane, you will see a `{}` button in the bottom toolbar.

Comment: ha - I've been using Chrome devtools for _ages_ and never noticed that :)   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nope. 
You must transfer the js to the client for it to work. With that you lose control over it. 
If you want to protect your intellectual property you could try to scramble the script. But that is considered bad practise and certainly will make your code be regarded as suspicious.

Comment: Ok, but as this is an business aplication,no one will really look.
How can I scramble the scripts? What programs are for doing such operations?
Thanks and Greetings,

Andy

Comment: If no one will look, then why do yo want to hide something ? Look for the work "obfuscaton" and you will find loads of solutions. But in my experience hiding own code is in 98% of all cases done cause coders are ashamed of their code. Make better code so that you can be proud of it and show it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no completely effective way.

Source minifiers can help a little, since it's very hard to put breakpoints in a file that only has one line of code ;-)

Minified code is <strike>reasonably</strike> trivially reversed back to readable code, though.    As @Ianzz pointed out, there's a de-minifier built right into the Chrome development tools!